# Is the any way to create String Literal Types in Java?

Tags: java, types

I'm new to Java.

I've been using Typescript to type my projects in the Front-end and I'm very used to creating [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) to limit possible inputs. Is there any easy way to this in Java?

For *eye candy*, here's how you create it in Typescript:

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The most similar thing is an [`enum` Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum Easing {
    EASE_IN, EASE_OUT, EASE_IN_OUT;
}
```

Comment: The enums *could* carry a string literal, so the original strings from the question are available.

Answer (score 0):

Could one do this by subclassing the [Segment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Segment.html) class and requiring that each subclass only allows in one of the allowed values? Then use sealed classes to only allow in those classes.

That way the values are constrained and are string like.